# Cannot find document after insert in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm dealing with a specific and simple case. I need some help, because I don't seem to be able to find the solution for this.

I've created a simple Schema and Model for MongoDB inside a javascript class.

```
this.UserSchema = new this.Schema({
    UserId: { type: String }, 
    IsToggle: { type: Boolean}
});

this.CalendarViewUserSchema = new this.Schema({ 
    _id:  { type: this.Schema.ObjectId },
    OwnerId: { type: String },
    UserList: [ this.UserSchema ] 
});

this.CalendarViewUser = this.mongoose.model('CalendarViewUsers',this.CalendarViewUserSchema);
```

This is in the constructor and I already have a lot of database interactions working, but I can't manage to get this one working.

I call this method for adding the new document:

```
AddCalendarViewUser : function(Id, UserToAddId){        
        NewUser = { UserId : UserToAddId, IsToggle : false };

        this.CalendarViewUser.update(
        { OwnerId : Id },
        { 
                       $set:  { OwnerId  : Id      },
           $push: { UserList : NewUser } 
                    },
        {upsert:true},
        function(err){
            if(err) {console.log(err);}
            else {console.log('Success');}
        }
    );
}, // this comma just introduces the next method.
```

This works fine. I can see the document is created correctly ,with Mongo Explorer, and if I use a .find() to retrieve everything from the collection, it shows up.

Then, I try to look for the inserted Doc with:

```
FindCalendarViewUser : function(Id){
    this.CalendarViewUser.findOne(
                { OwnerID : Id }, 
                function(err,result){

            if(err) {console.log(err);}
            else{console.log(result);}  
        }
        );
}
```

Here, it returns result = null.

The "Id" parameter is a String in both methods, just like the "OwnerId" in the Schema.

What am I doing wrong?

Both "OwnerId" and "Id" are the same. I also tried converting both to ObjectId, with no success.

Sorry for the code formatting.

EDIT:

Basically, I can find the Document using the _id field:

```
{ _id : '4fb0d1702edfda0104fc2b9f'}
```

But I can't find it with the OwnerId field:

```
{ OwnerId : '4f55e1a6c2c7287814000001'}
```

These values were taken directly from the database, so they correspond to the actual stored values.

EDIT 2:

I just figured out that if I insert the value by hand:

```
$set:  { OwnerId  : '4f55e1a6c2c7287814000001' }
```

and then search by the exact same string, it returns the document!

```
this.CalendarViewUser.findOne(
                    { OwnerID : '4f55e1a6c2c7287814000001'}
...
```

So I guess it is inserting some kind of garbage in the document's OwnerID field, or there was some kind of incompatibility with the field's Type. I will post the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, the callback function of the FindCalendarViewUser function needed parenteses around itself... it works now, just by adding those parentesis...

```
FindCalendarViewUser : function(Id){
    this.CalendarViewUser.findOne(
        { OwnerID : Id }, 
        (function(err,result){

            if(err) {console.log(err);}
            else{console.log(result);}  
        })
    );
}
```

Here's the working example. Jesus christ why. I could have sworn I had used without that in other ocasions.

EDIT: And now it is working without the parenteses. I'm sorry. It must be some tiny issue I have around the code. I just can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

typo?

```
if(err) {console.log(err);}
  else{console.log(err);} 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay on my feedback, it really is a typo.  The console.log on the file I'm testing is correct. I made the typo writting it here.

Any idea why this could be happening? Do you recollect stumbling upon this kind of sittuation? 

Thank you.

Comment: If I use the "_id" field as search parameter, I find the document. If I use the OwnerId field created by me, it doesn't find anything. 

I tried using the field OwnerId with ObjectId type with no luck.

Comment: I also tried inserting the search query manually like so:

{ OwnerID : '4f55e1a6c2c7287814000001' }   (which is the Id that is in that field as I can see in Mongo Explorer)